# How to work with a non-commited git file over multiple computers

Tags: git

Ok, I think this is a tricky question, and might even be "not possible", but here's my problem: I am currently working on a project using two computers at the same time. Using Git, I can change a file in one computer, commit it, upload it to the server and get it in the other computer. BUT commits should be made when you are ready to "commit" with a change. I don't like to commit unfinished files, or broken and untested ones, besides this will clutter all my revision history.

Is there a way that I can share a file in git over multiple computers, unfinished, untested files, something that won't be saved as a good restore point in the project? I thought about stashing, but as far as I know stashing is local, so I won't be able to retrieve my stash in the other computer.

Comment: You can commit and push in a seperate branch and delete the branch once done.

Comment: I thought about it, but it seems a little dirty...

Comment: delete is the cleanup :P

Comment: You’re asking if you can use Git to synchronize things without using the fundamental unit that Git uses to synchronize things. I would have used some file synchronization software in addition to Git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, stashing is local so it won't help you. One solution is to manually copy files from one computer to another, but that's missing the point of version control. Why don't you use your own branch for that?

That way you can create branch, and commit to it from both pc's. Read more about branches [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging). When merging that would put all your commits to master's history, though. But nothing is impossible.

There's --squash option when doing merge into master which merges all your branch-commits in one.

> --squash
>
> --no-squash
>
> Produce the working tree and index state as if a real merge happened (except for the merge information), but do not actually make
> a commit or move the HEAD, nor record $GIT_DIR/MERGE_HEAD to cause the
> next git commit command to create a merge commit. This allows you to
> create a single commit on top of the current branch whose effect is
> the same as merging another branch (or more in case of an octopus).

After finishing all your work, you can then use it to merge as (to make just single commit from it):

```
git checkout master
git merge --squash your_branch
```

Comment: I am marking this as the answer because I liked the idea of a new branch for sharing unfinished files and the squash option.....I just didn't understand much of the quoted text, if someone would care to explain it better I would appreciate it...

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot share untracked changes with Git. That is not what Git is for. Git tracks content, and if you don't tell it to track your changes, Git does *nothing* to store or transmit those changes.

Instead, don't worry so much about committing only when something is "done".

Commit constantly. Commit all the time. Work on a branch and, when you're done, squash that branch down to one (or a few) commits. Git makes branching and committing extremely cheap specifically to support this work-flow.

Comment: What do you mean by "squash that branch down to one (or a few) commits."? Merge? Or edit and erase the commits?

Comment: @mFeinstein You are free to rewrite the history of your branch as much as you want. If you want to take 100 commits and turn them into one clean "done" commit, you can easily do so. There are hundreds of thousands of pages out there about squashing commits.

Comment: I'd rather keep the commits... small commits are more helpful than one big commit containing many changes or many files... Given that you write good commit messages...

Comment: I never heard about it as "squashing", it looks like this will be what I will do...it just makes my skin crawl to delete something hahah

Answer (score 1):

I think this won't be possible instead you can make other branch and commit into that branch and don't merge that branch into main branch so that you code remains as it is to restore point.

Answer (score 1):

You need another branch. Get on your current branch -- the one you want to branch off of and then do:

`git checkout -b new_branch`

Then make your changes, commit them and upload that branch.

`git push -u origin new_branch`

then on the other computer pull that branch down.

Doing this method won't mess up any of your other files on your `master` branch and when you are ready to merge this `new_branch` into `master` you just merge it. Sharing uncommitted files is just not possible in git.